# Querying a table to get an historic count of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to write a Postgres query that will allow me to query the `users` table to count the evolution in the amount of users that were created through each month, grouping the results by month.

The `users` table has a `created_at` column.

E.g: Suppose that the app went live in December 2022 and during December 10 users where created, then the count for December should be 10. If another 5 users were created during January, the count for January should be 15 (10 from december plus 5 during January). And so on.

I think I have something that kind of works but I'm wondering if this is the right way to do it? Specially since I should be able to transform the raw SQL to ActiveRecord query afterwards.

```
select date_trunc('month', created_at) + interval '1 month' as month, 
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('month', created_at)) as historic_count
from users
```

Comment: think you want to account for years, otherwise you still start to get unexpected results --> ```select date_trunc('month', created_at) + interval '1 month' as month, 
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('year', created_at),  date_trunc('month', created_at)) as historic_count
from users```

Answer (score 1):

You're on right track. The following demonstrates a query that returns the described results:

```
WITH t(created_at) AS (
  VALUES ('2022-12-04'::date), ('2022-12-07'::date), ('2022-12-10'::date), ('2022-12-11'::date), ('2022-12-17'::date),
         ('2022-12-19'::date), ('2022-12-23'::date), ('2022-12-25'::date), ('2022-12-26'::date), ('2022-12-28'::date),
         ('2023-01-18'::date), ('2023-01-19'::date), ('2023-01-22'::date), ('2023-01-23'::date), ('2023-01-25'::date)
),
by_months AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('month', t.created_at) creation_month, count(*) AS creation_count
    FROM t
    GROUP BY creation_month
)
SELECT creation_month::date AS month, sum(creation_count) OVER (ORDER BY creation_month) AS historic_count
  FROM by_months
  ORDER BY creation_month;
```

The first step is to get the creation counts per month. A cummulative sum of these counts is then computed in the top level query. There is an implicit `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` frame definition associated with the windowed `sum` aggregate function.

Because of the aggregations, this is a difficult query to implement in ActiveRecord without using some explicit SQL.